# Dialogflow Facebook Integration is not responding to page messages but responding to postbacks

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have two Facebook messenger bot. Both of them are connected to dialogflow with different gmail address. Today I am facing a very odd problem. The problem is both of the bot are responding to postbacks button instantly but they are not responding to page messages or quick replies. These replies comes very lately (almost 5-10 min late). So where is the problem. It is the Facebook or dialogflow. Please help me.

Comment: Could you provide more details, additional overview? When it started, did you change something lately? If you will use just one bot, is behavior the same? Are you getting any kind of error/warning?

Comment: It was a facebook messenger webhook delivery system problem. It is resolved by Facebook.

Comment: Please elaborate your comment and post it as an answer. It might be useful for other users with similar problem.